# Run crystal report on linux server

Tags: linux, crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report (version 2013) on my local pc. Now I want to deploy the .rpt file in the production which is a linux server. Which software would I like to install there to make it run the report there? Is it necessary to install crystal server installation or is there any other way around to run just the rpt file.